# Why do I get "Error 6060" when I try to use DBD::Advantage with a 64-bit perl on Linux?

Tags: linux, perl, 64-bit, advantage-database-server

I realize that I am attempting to go beyond the "supported" behavior of the manf's released drivers for Perl, after all they have only released it in package with x86 .so's.

However, since I cannot use their package with x64 Perl on a RHEL 5.4 x86_64 box, and maintaining a seperate install of x86 Perl just for this *one package*, I have made an attempt to get this puppy working thanks to released 64-bit .so's that accompany *other* driver packages for Advantage.

What I have done to this point:

- download beta 10 DBI drivers, in 32
- download beta 10 PHP extension (it contains 32 and x86_64)
- copy the required DLLs into the ads-lib location (eg /usr/local/ads/lib64)
- compile the Perl DBI driver with the path to the lib64's .so's
- Good compilation, good install, good use.

The problem is that I always get :

> failed: [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL][ASA] Error 6060:  Advantage Database Server not available on specified server.  axServerConnect (SQL-HY000)(DBD: db_login/SQLConnect err=-1)

Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: fixed package name in post title
EDIT: Updated title.

It appears that it's not just the x64 perl, but the RHEL 5.4 underneath that may be interfering. As commented below, I managed to shoe-horn a x86 perl onto the system, and compile the DBD::Advantage 9.99, and later replacing that with 9.10, and none of these x86 would connect either. Neither library (9.99 or 9.10) in either bit-edness will connect from this x86_64 server to the windows server's UNC path.

I have successfully mounted this share without problems, but still I cannot seem to connect to the 9.1. I have tried:
\hostname\PATH
\FQDN\PATH
\IP\PATH
and all of these variations with the port (default) 6262 included.

My windows machine connects fine, with both 9.1 and 9.99 from strawberry perl.

Comment: I'm attempting to connect to a 9.1 server, and should have no problems. My string is a UNC path on a remote host, and I have added the port to no avail. For the heck of it, I placed the remote servers ip in the hosts file, FQDN and host, again with no avail.

Thx edgar, but unfortunately i'm still stuck. At the moment I am trying to force x86 side-by-side with x86_64 to test the "supported" drivers.


connection string: dbi:Advantage:DataDirectory=\\windows\medisoft\STLUKES\MEDIDATA\mwddf.add;uid=user;pwd=password;

Comment: A "newer" client can not connect to an "older" server.  In other words you can not connect a 10 client to a 9.1 server.

Comment: Ok, I managed to shoe-horn a x86 perl in, load DBI and the x86 9.99 (10 beta) DBD::Advantage. Seems I get the same error. Wonky. Still, any ideas anyone?

Comment: As for anyone who might ask, I verified the windows 32-bit 9.99 DBD does indeed access the 9.1 server perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

Check the host file on the Linux server and make sure the name of the server uses the actual IP rather then the loopback address.

Also, since you updated the client, did you also install/update the 10 beta server?

Finally, what is your connection string?  Have you tried adding the port to the connection string?

Comment: Edgar, why would a windows machine complacently connect to an older server, but not a linux machine?

Comment: Have you added the LINUX ip address (the real one) to the LINUX Host file?  I am not sure why, but if just the loop back address is there is can give unexpected results.

Comment: I have the box's own IP configured in its host file already as that is part of the requirements for getting Oracle installed on it. And the perl isntallation being used is seperate from Oracle's self-used perl